# How can this recursive function be improved?

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

The code in `walkTree` walks a file tree represented in a list of `fileTree` nodes. It does what I want, which is to recursively print each entry in the tree. But I have the feeling that it could be much improved. I also think I am sabotaging tail recursion by running 2 `visit statements at the end of the patern matching.

```
type 'a fileTree =
  | File of 'a
  | Folder of 'a * ('a fileTree list)

let fileTreeStructure = [
  File "file1.txt" ;
  Folder ("testFolder1", [Folder ("nestedFolder1", [])]) ;
  File "test1.txt";
  Folder ("testFolder2", [Folder ("nestedFolder2", [])]) ;
  File "test2.txt";
]

let walkTree tree =
  let rec visit = function
    | [] -> print_string "\n"
    | File f :: t ->
      Printf.printf "file: %s\n" f ;
      visit t
    | Folder (name, contents) :: t ->
      Printf.printf "name: %s\n" name ;
      visit contents ;
      visit t in
  visit tree;;

walkTree fileTreeStructure
```

What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, i'd separate `list` and `fileTree` matching:

```
let walkTree tree =
  let rec visit = function
    | File f -> Printf.printf "file: %s\n" f
    | Folder (name, contents) ->
        Printf.printf "name: %s\n" name;
        List.iter visit contents
  in visit tree

let _ = List.iter walkTree fileTreeStructure
```

**Edit** (with *@nlucaroni* suggestion; i've also replaced `List.iter` function for illustration):

If you want the `walkTree` function to accept literally `string fileTree list` (instead of `string fileTree` as in the first example):

```
let walkTree tree =
  let rec iter = function
    | [] -> ()
    | a::l -> visit a; iter l
  and visit = function
    | File f -> Printf.printf "file: %s\n" f
    | Folder (name, contents) ->
        Printf.printf "name: %s\n" name;
        iter contents
  in iter tree
```

Comment: You could use mutual recursion on the Folder branch to call the outer List.iter on the list (once named).